# Two variables in one equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am currently having some trouble getting through the following exercise:

"There are $25$ apples in a basket in which teacher eats an $X$ amount of them and gives the remaining apples to Y amount of students, where each student receives 1,5333 apples. How many students are there?"

I've made this into a simple equation that contains two variables: $\frac{25-X} {Y} = 1,5333$, $X$ being the amounts of apples eaten by the teacher and $Y$ being the number of students.

No matter what I try, I simply end up getting answers that aren't precise enough. I can't think of any other way than rounding the answer multiple times, however that sounds like a poor way of solving this.

Is there any ideal ways of solving this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $1.5333... = \frac{23}{15}$, which means you probably have $23$ apples given to $15$ students. Remembering that both the number of students and the number of apples should be integers, means that this is the most probable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $1.5333333$ means $1.5\overline 3$

Then, you can use the standard method to determine that $$x=1.5\overline 3\\
10x = 15.3\overline 3\\
9x = 13.8\\
x = \frac{138}{90} = \frac{46}{30}=\frac{23}{15}$$

---

You know that $X$ is an integer between $0$ and $25$, and you know that $$Y=\frac{25-X}{1.5333333} = \frac{15(25-X)}{23}$$

is also an integer.

Knowing that $23$ is prime should now tell you what the value of $25-X$ must be in order for $Y$ to not be a fraction.